# Word Searching using fgetc

Tags: c

I am trying to make word search using fgetc. I understand what fgetc does but i am getting seg fault. on running the gdb test, i returns the following. Is there an easier way to implement the search function?? i am new to programming.
thank you for the help.

```
#0  0x00007ffff7aa4c64 in getc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040070c in main ()
```

Where am i going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isAlpha(char c)
{
    if( c >= 'A' && c <='Z' || c >= 'a' && c <='z' || c >= '0' && c <= '9' )
    {
        return 1;        
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int CheckFunctionn(int length, int message_counter, char ref_word[], char newmessage[])
{
    int newCounter = 0;
    int counterSuccess = 0;

    while(newCounter < length)
    {
        if(ref_word[newCounter] == newmessage[newCounter + message_counter])
        {
            counterSuccess++;
        }
        newCounter++;
    }

    if(counterSuccess == length)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char message[300];
    int counter = 0;
    int ref_length = 0;
    int alphaCounter = 0;
    int alphaCounterTime = 0;
    int messageCounter = 0;
    int word_counter = 0;

    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;

    //long fileLength;
    //int bufferLength;
    //char readFile;
    //int forkValue;

    input = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    output = fopen(argv[3],"w");

    int c;
    c = fgetc(input);

    while(c != EOF)
    {
        while((argv[1])[ref_length] !='\0')
        {
            // if string is "HEY", (argv[1]) is HEY, ref_counter is the length
            // which in this case will be 3.
            ref_length++; //<-- takes care of the length.
        }

        while(alphaCounter < ref_length)
        {
            // this will add to alphaCounter everyetime alphaCT is success.
            alphaCounterTime += isAlpha((argv[1])[alphaCounter]);
            alphaCounter++;
        }

        if(alphaCounterTime != ref_length)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if((messageCounter == 0 ) && (message[messageCounter + ref_length] == ' ' || message[messageCounter] == '\n' || message[messageCounter]== '\t')) // counts the whole things and brings me to space
        {
            // compare the message with the word
            word_counter += CheckFunctionn(ref_length, messageCounter, argv[1], message);
        }

        if((message[messageCounter] == ' ' || message[messageCounter] == '\n' || message[messageCounter]== '\t')  && (message[messageCounter +  ref_length + 1] == ' ' || message[messageCounter + ref_length + 1] == '\n' || message[messageCounter + ref_length + 1]== '\t'))
        {
            word_counter += CheckFunctionn(ref_length, messageCounter + 1, argv[1], message);
        }

        if((message[messageCounter]== ' '|| message[messageCounter] == '\n' || message[messageCounter]== '\t') && (messageCounter + ref_length+1)== counter) //<-- this means the length of the message is same
        {
            word_counter += CheckFunctionn(ref_length, messageCounter + 1, argv[1], message);
        }

        messageCounter++;        
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps compile with debugging info (`-g`) and step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: i get the following 
<code>
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff7aa4c64 in getc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040070c in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe4f8) at sum.c:67
</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost certainly failing to open the input file.  If `fopen` fails, it returns `NULL`, and calling `fgetc(NULL)` has undefined behavior, and a segmentation fault is one possible outcome of undefined behavior.

You need to check for errors and handle then accordingly.  You also need to check if your program was given sufficient arguments.  Here's one way to handle them:

```
if (argc < 3)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input-file output-file\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if (input == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

output = fopen(argv[2],"w");
if (output == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening output file %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: just a query, when i execute the program, i do cat input.txt and it shows me the input file, does it still mean that there is an error in input file?

Answer (score 1):

You only read one character into `c`, then loop `while(c != EOF)` which is almost always an infinite loop. Inside that loop, you increment `messageCounter` which you use to walk past the end of an array -- boom!

Comment: how could i fix it? i understand what you are saying , but if you could hint me on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, `argc` is 2, but you refer to `argv[2]` which would be the *third* element of the args, and will be `NULL`. The `FILE *` is going to end up being `NULL` too (because it's invalid to pass `NULL` to `fopen`).

Answer (score -1):

It will be very easy if you use `strcmp` function in this...

What you have to do is first find the length of ur file using `ftell` and after that allocate that much memory then fill that memory using `fgetc` or `fgets` or any other file function...then just use `strcmp` function on that....bingo!!!!! :)